# How to create one generic function from two similiar?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, generics, typeorm

I have two this same function, but working on different entities,

```
    async getUserName(userId: number): Promise<string> {
        const user = await this.conn.getRepository(User).findOne(userId);
        return user .name;
    }

    async getOrderName(orderId: number): Promise<string> {
        const order = await this.conn.getRepository(Order).findOne(orderId);
        return order .name;
    }
```

how to create on place of this two function, a one generic function, which would only take entities and `id` number and would return the given name like a guide in the functions above?

ps. I'm using typescript and typeorm

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely make the difference between two functions into an argument of said function

```
type TRepository = User | Order
async getName(id: number, rep: TRepository): Promise<string> {
    const entity = await this.conn.getRepository(rep).findOne(id);
    return entity.name;
}
```

Comment: where can i put `type TRepository = User | Order`? into `constructor`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending id, you can send entire object, Based on that you can find the repository to search and get id from it.

Also, since you are using await, your function will return a string and not a promise.

```js
async getOrderName(searchObj: User|Order): string {
  const field = searchObj.instanceOf(User) ? User : Order
  const value = await this.conn.getRepository(field).findOne(searchObj.id);
  return value.name;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also try `Object.constructor`

```js
async getOrderName(searchObj: User|Order): string {
  const value = await this.conn
    .getRepository(searchObj.constructor)
    .findOne(searchObj.id);
  return value.name;
}
```

Comment: throw me `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'unknown'.` from this two funciton

Comment: Try `const value: User|Order|null = await this.conn...; return !!value ? value.name : undefined`

Comment: still this same problem

Comment: Question: Which approach are you trying? Are you getting output in `value`?

Comment: i try to get only `name` from the `value` by `value.name`

Comment: The issue is, type of object that is returned is not resolved. You can typecase as well. But there its really difficult to help with partial info.